# Renaming css code in grid

Tags: css

I am having problems renaming some classes from a grid I'm working on.

The current code is this:

```
.col,
   .cols {
    margin-left: 4%; 
  }

  .col:first-child,
  .cols:first-child {
    margin-left: 0; 
  }


  .one.col,
  .one.cols, { 
    width: 4.66666666667%; 
  }
```

And then the html code is:

```
<div class="one col">One</div>
  <div class="eleven cols">Eleven</div>
```

The above code works but I need to change the class names to work so the html code goes like this:

```
 <div class="one-col">One</div>
  <div class="eleven-cols">Eleven</div>
```

My question is... How do I change the code below so that the above html works?

```
.col,
   .cols {
    margin-left: 4%; 
  }

  .col:first-child,
  .cols:first-child {
    margin-left: 0; 
  }


  .one.col,
  .one.cols, { 
    width: 4.66666666667%; 
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tweak the CSS:

```
.one-col,.eleven-cols{
    margin-left: 4%; 
}

.one-col:first-child,.eleven-cols:first-child {
    margin-left: 0; 
}


.one-col { 
    width: 4.66666666667%; 
}

.eleven-cols {
    width: 51.3333333334%;
}
```

Comment: I need to add the - to the html and use 1 class instead of 2...so "one col" would be "one-col"

Comment: so for these theres no shortcut like asterisks that i can use? .one-col,.eleven-cols{
    margin-left: 4%; 
}

.one-col:first-child,.eleven-cols:first-child {
    margin-left: 0; 
}

Comment: @Satch3000 I was assuming you had other code that you didn't include, so I didn't use asterisks. But if those two HTML lines are all the code, then go ahead and do `*{ margin-left: 4%;} *:first-child{ margin-left:0;}`

Comment: basically .one-col, two-col .... goes all the way to twelve with is why i was looking for asterisks

Comment: Oh I see, you're trying to do something like Bootstrap, with 12 column pages...Yes, go use asterisks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87030/discussion-between-thejuniorprogrammer-and-satch3000).

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear on why you need only one class because we can declare multiple classes in class attribute.

But anyways. hope below code will help you,

```
.one-col{
    margin-left: 4%; 
    width: 4.66666666667%; 
}
.eleven-cols{
    margin-left: 4%; 
    width: 51.3333333334%;
}
.one-col:first-child,.eleven-cols:first-child{
    margin-left: 0; 
}
```